# Enforcing ordered communication between actors

Tags: azure-service-fabric, orleans

I have a problem which requires my actors to process messages in the order they were sent.  In Akka, messages between actor A and actor B are always guaranteed to arrive in the order sent.  This does not appear to be the case in Reliable Actors in Service Fabric.  In my test cases, the messages are received in non-deterministic order.

I can force ordering by not sending the next message until the first message is processed, but this defeats the entire point.  I really want to send and forget the messages, but know that they will be processed in order by the receiving actor.

Has anyone seen a pattern for doing this?  I think Orleans Actors has the same out of order message possibility.  Perhaps an Orleans solution would work here as well.

Comment: What does fire and forget look like between two Actors? Both are single threaded right? So ordering happens naturally I assume?

Comment: Yes, both are single threaded, but the messages are routed through the Service Fabric infrastructure.  If actor A sends three messages to actor B (M1, M2, M3) they may be processed by actor B in a different order, say M2, M3, M1,

Comment: But how can actor A send M1, M2 and M3 without waiting on any of them? In that case you are doing something special with threads, right? Otherwise I would assume because M1 should be handled before A can send M2, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: The sending of message is asynchronous.  So I can send a message and then send another message without having to wait for the result of the first.

Each actor is single threaded, but there is also the Service Fabric intermediary that is dealing out the messages.  So with two actors, there are at least three threads involved.

Comment: According to my understanding, when you call a method on an ActorProxy, when that method finishes, the call is executed by the ActorProxy. Although it is async (awaitable), it is not asynchronous. Do you have pointers to documentation that explains what you state?

Answer (score 4):

Orleans does not guarantee the order of message deliver to actors (unless you send them one at a time as you have already discounted):

https://github.com/akka/akka-meta/blob/master/ComparisonWithOrleans.md#messaging-guarantees

However, it is possible to control ordering if you're using streams in Orleans (with the correct underlying stream provider):

http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Orleans-Streams/